# Send Strings From RPI to IOS using bluetooth

Tags: python, iphone, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, rfcomm

Am sending strings of data from my RPI to android device using a python script.Am using RFCOMM protocol for communicating with android device continously, and it works perfectly.

```
import bluetooth

sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
sock.connect((host, main_port))
sock.send('example')
sock.recv(1024)
```

Above is a sample code that i have used in my python script.
Now i need to implement same in IOS devices.Is it possible to use RFCOMM protocol to send data to IOS device(Iphone6) from RPI or is there any restriction for doing this.

If this is not possible how will i implement same using BLE in python ?

Comment: @ Zealous I want to send data from RPI to android device. Here what are host, main_port ?